# Changing Line color on focus inside input or textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I've come across a lot of online editors (for ex. [dillinger](http://dillinger.io)), where, when the user clicks inside the textarea, the line which has focus changes color. I'm curious to know how stuff works here. Not just the line color but any styling which is possible in an editor's editing portion, I'm completely unaware of it. I came across the concept of zebra striping while googling about it, but I don't think it has anything to do with editable portions where a single line has to be focused dynamically.

It seems achievable though, but how?

**PS:** Please don't provide any existing tool/utility to achieve this. I prefer reinventing the wheel. If it is not an easy road, at least provide the best to your knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a textarea, but it has many divs underneath it (i.e. a lower z-index) to style it in a particular way. More specifically this is an [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) so they may detail some of their effects in the documentation.

For example, if you inspect the source of that page you will find the class `ace_active-line` which you can see is a div that is located underneath the textarea. The textarea has a transparent background which is why you're able to see the div underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Most simply put this is achieved through the utilization of CSS selectors, in specific **:focus**.

Even with layered divs and other accompanying elements, you can style these divs when the **topmost** div is in focus, for instance:

```
input div.inner-input {
   border: 1px black;
}

input:focus div.inner-input {
   border: 1px orange;
}
```

This can also be further achieved through jQuery to edit another div's class or attributes when an input comes into focus.

```
input.onFocus() {
    $('.under-div').addClass('active-line');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to reinvent the wheel, you'll need to build the roads to use the wheels on too.
In this case you cannot be working in a textarea (as mentioned in the tags). Instead, the rendering of the editor will be all yours.

One of the approaches would be:

1. Create a `<div>` container for the area where the text will entered.
2. Create another `<div>` inside the first one. This will be our overlay. Make sure that it has a low `z-index`. Let's say it's `z-index: 1`.
3. Create a third `<div>` container under the first one. This will be the actual text editor. It has to have transparent `background` and a higher `z-index`.
4. Put a `<div>` inside the container #2. It's going to be our row highlighter.

For every line in the editor you'll need to render its own `<div>`, with a `<span>` inside of it for text. Yup, a lot of custom code: you'll need to write proper functions to push new `<div>` when user hits Enter to start a new line and so on and so forth.

You'll also need to make sure that the height of these row-div's is fixed to a certain minimum value (*up to you to figure out the value and the formula behind the calculation, probably something based on the window height, maybe user preferences or font size*). It can grow though, for example when user has word wrapping enabled.

When all of it is done the real magic can begin: highlighting. Let's imagine we have a three-line document loaded. It will look like this:

```
<div id="textContainer">
    <div id="overlay" style="z-index: 1">
        <div id="highlighter" style="background: yellow; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="textEditor" style="background: transparent; z-index: 100;">
        <div>
            <span>Line 1</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Line 2</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Line 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can determine the exact position and width of the `textContainer` on the screen: it's required to easily (and with little performance overhead) handle different screen/window sizes.

When user focuses on a certain row you'll need to run some JavaScript which grabs the current `top` and `height` values of the row (`<div>`) the user focused on and sets the `<div id="highlighter">` location and height to be the same.

Comment: How do you plan to take input from user without an `input` or `textarea`?

Answer (score -3):

Use css focus function to change the outline color when focus on input box.

```
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gwLgckvf/